# Not all custom templates show up in Theme file editor

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to edit the source of some of my custom templates. I have made extensive modifications to a child theme.

But only some of the custom templates show up in Theme file editor or are present as .html files on the file server.

Where else should I be looking for these templates? I understand that WP stores some changes in the database - but I've had no luck searching this for traces of the templates.

Comment: template parts got moved to under patterns in 6.3, note that the templates list also has pagination which isn't always obvious